# Dynamic input table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic table using html and javascript where the user enters number of rows, and want all table cells to be of input type

```
function createTable() {
  var a, b, tableElem, rowElem, colElem;

  a = 7
  b = 5

  if (a == "" || b == "") {
    alert("Please enter some numeric value");
  } else {
    tableElem = document.createElement('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      rowElem = document.createElement('tr');

      for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        colElem = document.createElement('td');
        colElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j + 1)); //to print cell number
        rowElem.appendChild(colElem);
      }

      tableElem.appendChild(rowElem);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(tableElem);


  }
```

I found this code, but how to make all cells of input type?

Comment: Use `document.createElement('input')` instead of `document.createTextNode()`

Comment: You should not append multiple children in a loop to the document, it will slow down the performance of your app. Better use a `DocumentFragment` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment and append it to the body after looping :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `input` elements inside each table cell, an option would be setting the `contenteditable` attribute for each cell.

A simple event listener to detect `focusout` can trigger whatever steps you want to perform, such as extracting the entered text and setting it to variables for further computations.

This working snippet uses a table written in html but the same principle can be applied to the table added dynamically.

```js
const cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (let i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {

cells[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
cells[i].addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
});

} // next cell;
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<p>enter text in cells below:</p>
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```